# Spotlight can't find Google Chrome app

Tags: spotlight

Why does Spotlight want to search Google for `Chrome` rather than launch the app Chrome?

For some reason, searching for Chrome in Spotlight yields numerous suggestions (a Google search for "Chrome", the definition of "chrome", the Wikipedia entry for "Google Chrome") but none of them is the Chrome app on my computer—why doesn't the app show up?

---

**GIF:**

[image: https://gyazo.com/fc5b1244f0ec2bb4335fdb84e1b95331]

**Image:**

[image: Spotlight Chrome]

Comment: Here's a gif of me searching Spotlight for Chrome (and it working): https://openload.co/stream/f-82TXJTy1w~1487714681~108.29.0.0~m8-YFPnh?mime=true

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps or not! If it doesn't I'd be happy to help more :D.

Comment: after all these years, this bug is still repeating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting Spotlight's index of your files and reinitializing it should allow it to find your apps in the Applications folder.

**1. Turn off spotlight:**

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```

**2. Unload its metadata plist:**

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

**3. Load its metadata plist:**

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

**4. Turn on Spotlight again:**

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

Comment: This worked.  Marking as the Answer.

Comment: @GN. Nice! Happy to help.

Comment: Sigh...  `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`  Might want to mention that this can be an issue in  your answer.

Comment: I got the same error as @JonathanvanClute however turning Spotlight on and off with those commands was enough to make it index again, and solve my problem (VMware in this case).

Comment: Doing only steps 1 and 4 worked for me.  (As mentioned by others, step 2 requires  System Integrity Protection to be turned off.)

Comment: This still works in 2021 w/ OSX 12.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the "Applications" option is selected in System Preferences >> Spotlight >> Search Results:

[image]

If Google Chrome is installed (and in the Applications folder) pressing <kbd>Command⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and typing "chrome" will make Spotlight display the application as the top hit:

[image]

Comment: @owlswipe I danced a jig the day I found out Preview.app has arrow, text and shape [annotations](http://imgur.com/a/olTow)! :D

Comment: ohh yeah! And the [just taking a screenshot of the window with a shadow](http://www.uponmyshoulder.com/blog/2010/screenshots-and-os-x-capturing-a-single-window/) is on point.

Comment: @owlswipe SRS BSNS!!! Windows has their "snipping tool" and "alt prnt scrn" and all, but cmd+shift+3 & 4 are so sublimely superior - especially cmd+shift+4, spacebar. (I just kissed my mac)

Comment: also the QuickTimePlayer (& iMovie) screen capture with select area is supremely amazing (I also recently discovered the [SoundFlower.kext](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) to MIDI route system audio so QT can grab that too...) and with a little FFMPEG conversion to .gif - it's a whole new world of lolcats!

Comment: I would fire back with tricks of my own but when I hear FFMPEG I know I've been way outclassed :))

Comment: @owlswipe oh nOz - naw, I just know enough to do basic stuff, please do tell - I love mac tricks!

Comment: mostly I just like ffmpeg cuz its FREE :P

Answer (score 0):

I know an an answer has already been accepted, but my problem was different so adding my solution here in case others are in the same situation.

My problem was the app in question being incorrectly named in the 'Name & Extension' settings for the file even though Finder showed the name correctly (Right-click on app -> Get info -> Name & Extension) - I don't know how that happened (possibly my kid playing with my laptop) but if the name in the textbox isn't the same as the app name, Spotlight, or [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) in my case, won't be able to find it.

[image] [image]

Just enter the correct app name with `.app` extension in the textbox and you should be good to go.

Comment: If your problem was different, why are you posting the answer to it here?  Search Ask Different to see if the question was already asked and post it there.  If not, feel free to ask a new question and post the answer.

Comment: @Allan did you read my answer in full? Because although the cause to my problem may have been different, it was still the same 'problem' of "Spotlight can't find Google Chrome app" - no reason why I should pollute the database with a similar problem asked differently. People asking the same question will read a different answer if the accepted answer doesn't work for them, and they will find their solution in the other one ;)

Comment: Read your first paragraph.....